# C++ Determine if K can be expressed as a sum of prime factors of N

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I am writing a program that will solve [The Centrifuge Problem](https://mattbaker.blog/2018/06/25/the-balanced-centrifuge-problem/), and I am having trouble with a particular part of my algorithm. I need to take 2 integer variables N and K, and determine if K can be expressed as a Sum of the Prime Factors of N.

For example N = 21, and K = 6: Prime factors of 21 are 3 x 7. 6 can be expressed as 3 + 3 so this would be true.
Another example N = 21, K = 11. 11 cannot be expressed as any combination of 3 or 7 so false.

In my program, the best idea I have had thus far to solve this problem is find the prime factors of N using the following code and then storing the values into a vector:

```
vector<int> PrimeFactors(int n)
{
    vector<int> factors;

    while (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        factors.push_back(2);
        n = n / 2;
    }

    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i + 2)
        while (n % i == 0)
        {
            factors.push_back(i);
            n = n / i;
        }

    if (n > 2)
        factors.push_back(n);

    return factors;
}
```

The problem is, I have no idea how to take the items of the vector and determine if my value for K can be expressed as a sum of any of those values.

Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction or maybe suggest a better approach to solving this particular part of my problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem

Comment: Your problem consists of two parts, the first part is finding the prime factors of `n` which you found them, and the second part is to determine whether they satisfy your need or not? You already write the code for the first part so you could try to solve the second part with *Dynamic Programming*  https://www.sanfoundry.com/dynamic-programming-solutions-change-making-problem/

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
bool isSum(const std::vector<int>& F, const int K)
{
  for (const auto& f: F)
  {
    if (f > K)
    {
      break;
    }
    else if (f == K)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else if (f < K)
    {
      if (isSum(F, K - f))
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

I'm assuming here that all the factors in the vector `F` are sorted in increasing order.

However, I suspect your factorization function won't work correctly.